# PHP does not return variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, return-value

I have menu.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div style="width:150px;height:30px;border:1px solid blue;">
                    <a href="http://localhost/SCW_Files//Form_AddWood.html">Add wood to DataBase</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="http://localhost/SCW_Files//Form_AddBowl.html">Add bowl to DataBase</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="http://localhost/SCW_Files//Form_AddTime.html">Add time to DataBase</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Which calls Form_AddBowl.html:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <form action="Form_AddBowl.php" method="post"><br /><br />
            <div style="color:sienna;margin-left:300px;">
                <br />
                <div style="color:blue; serif; text-decoration:underline;">
                    <h1>Add bowl to database</h1>
                </div>
                <br /><br />
                BowlCode: <input type="text" name="code"><br /><br />
                SpeciesYear: <input type="text" name="species"><br /><br />
                ProduceHeading: <input type="text" name="heading"><br /><br />
                BowlDetails: <input type="text" name="details"><br /><br />
                BowlPrice: <input type="text" name="price"><br /><br />
                <input type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Which, on submit, calls Form_AddBowl.php:

```
            <?php include("menu.php"); ?>
        <?php
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx");
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db("scw-db", $con);

        $sql="INSERT INTO tblsplintersbowlinventory (txtProductBowlCode, txtSpeciesSeq, txtProductHeading, txtProductBowlDetails, curProductBowlPriceAsked)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[code]', '$_POST[species]','$_POST[heading]', '$_POST[details]', '$_POST[price]')";

        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
          }
        echo "<br>1 record added";

        mysql_close($con);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the DB, the field "txtProductBowlCode" is defined as "unique".

The menu works fine, and Form_AddBowl.html shows the form for the new bowl.

And the Form_AddBowl seems to work, as long as the code field is unique.

If the code is unique it returns "***1 record added***", if it is not it returns:

```
Error: Duplicate entry 'Maple15-001' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Problem 1:
How do I get this to show the result "Maple15-001 record added" when Maple15-001 is a new code?

I tried:

```
echo '<br>';
echo "$code record added";
```

But that returns the error:

```
    Notice: Undefined variable: code in C:\xampp\htdocs\SCW_Files\Form_AddBowl.php on line 20
record added
```

Problem 2:
This returns to the Menu instead of the Bowl form - I may want to enter several bowls in succession, and if the code was a duplicate replace it with a new one.

EDIT:

I made the changes Andrew suggested, this is the code:

```
    <?php include("menu.php"); ?>
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxxxxx","xxxxx");
    if (!$con)
    {
        echo 'Could not connect to database ' . mysql_error();
    } else {
        mysql_select_db("scw-db", $con);

        $sql="INSERT INTO tblsplintersbowlinventory (txtProductBowlCode, txtSpeciesSeq, txtProductHeading, txtProductBowlDetails, curProductBowlPriceAsked)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[code]', '$_POST[species]','$_POST[heading]', '$_POST[details]', '$_POST[price]')";
        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
        {
            echo '<br>Could not save new bowl ';
            echo $_POST['code'];
            echo '<br>Error: ' . mysql_error();
        } else {
            echo '<br>';
            echo $_POST['code'];
            echo " record added";
        }
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}
?>
        <form action="" method="post"><br /><br />
            <div style="color:sienna;margin-left:300px;">
                <br />
                <div style="color:blue; serif; text-decoration:underline;">
                    <h1>Add bowl to database</h1>
                </div>
                <br /><br />
                BowlCode: <input type="text" name="code"><br /><br />
                SpeciesYear: <input type="text" name="species"><br /><br />
                ProduceHeading: <input type="text" name="heading"><br /><br />
                BowlDetails: <input type="text" name="details"><br /><br />
                BowlPrice: <input type="text" name="price"><br /><br />
                <input type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I call the script, I see:

```
    Could not save new bowl '; echo $_POST['code']; echo '
Error: ' . mysql_error(); } else { echo '
'; echo $_POST['code']; echo " record added"; } } mysql_close($con); } ?>
```

Shown at the top of the page - ***BEFORE*** anything is entered...

Below that is the form.

When I enter a new bowl into the fields and hit submit, the text at the top does not change, the entries I made are gone, and the test bowl has not been entered in the database, which ***DOES*** happen with the original version.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, you need to echo the post variable like so:

```
echo $_POST['code'];
```

also in your mysql query, you are missing quotations in the post variables as well, one way to fix it is:

```
'`{$_POST['code']}'`
```

or:

```
'".$_POST['code']."'
```

For your second problem, you could take the `addbowl.php` code, and wrap it in a "if request method is post" statement, so new stuff is added to database only when the form is submitted,  and then put the html for the form underneath it, of course not in between `PHP` tags. That way even when posting, you stay on the same page with the form.

Comment: OK, that solved the first problem - thanks. I'll look at the second fix in the morning. Also, when the MySQL query gets an error message (as in the above) how do I flag that so I can handle it myself?

Comment: Well currently you have a die statement happening after it checks and finds the query failed, you could have your program do something other than die, such as set a session flag or something.